# Running a Dynamic Model as Steady State with Time Varying Inputs

Tags: dynamics, aerospace-engineering, modeling, simulation

I am attempting to run a dynamic model of a waste heat recovery system (Brayton Cycle with intercooling) on IDAES but I keep getting errors on initilization seemingly no matter what I do. My work around to this is by using the steady state model which initializes and solves just fine, but have it iterate through a for loop wherein the conditions for compressor and turbine temperature inputs would vary with time.

Would it be possible to encomposs a transient simulation using a method like this or would I be leaving out details?

Thanks for the input!

For background: IDAES is a Python Library which is why I mention introducing the for loops.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you set the next iteration based on ALL the results of the previous then it should work but painfully slow.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as steady state in reality, so the steady state models are used when dynamic and some other effects are negligible. If the variations are slow enough, you could use series of steady states, but I suspect that is not the case here.

However, steady state analysis may be a good starting point for the dynamic analysis. Dynamic analysis should have fewer problems starting, when the initial conditions are in steady state.